# Display local picture in WebKitView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I need to display some pictures in a WebKitView. This pictures are stored in my Documents directory. The WebKitView content is builded programmatically from a (very) long string.

Here is how I call it :

```
@IBOutlet weak var descView: UIView!

var webView: WKWebView!
let localFile = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/image.png"
let htmlString = "<img src=\"\(localFile)\" />" // for example

let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    webConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = .all
}        

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: descView.frame.width, height: descView.frame.height), configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.allowsLinkPreview = true
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self

let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
let baseURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: bundlePath)

webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: baseURL)
descView.addSubview(webView)
```

But the picture is not present.

[Edit] The baseURL is needed since I use some scripts from the bundle. [image: scripts]

The htmlString could be :

```
let htmlHeader = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>\n" +
"<head><script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"MathJax-2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML\"></script></head>\n" +
"<body style=\"font-size:16pt; text-align:justify;\">"
let htmlFooter = "</body></html>"
let htmlString = htmlHeader + "<img src=\"\(localFile)\" /> $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$" + htmlFooter
```

This should show the picture and above some latex text. The latex is ok, no the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your `localFile` path and/or your `baseURL` is incorrect.

1. Is your app running in a sandbox? Is the image really located at `NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/image.png"`? Did you print the path to check?
2. Is `NSURL.fileURL(withPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)` the correct `baseURL`? You are loading your image from the home directory but the `baseUrl` from the app bundle. This cannot work

Did you try

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

or

```
let htmlString = "<img src=\"image.png\" />"
let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents")
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: baseURL)
```

?

Also, consider using a real HTML string not just the image tag like:

```
    let htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "img{position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}" +
            "</style>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<img src='\(localFile)'/>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>"
```

Comment: I need this baseURL. I've edited my post to explain why. May be it is not possible to use both scripts from the bundle and display a file from the Documents directory ? (I'm sure the image path is good)

Comment: This is only possible if you use an URL with an absolute path for your image. Did you try `let localFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: localFile)` and `let htmlString = "<img src=\"\(localFileURL)\" />"`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, may be not the best but it works:

```
let filePath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/image.jpg"
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
    let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 85)
    let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength76Characters)
    let htmlString = "<img src=\"data:image/jpep;base64,\(base64String)\" alt=\"image.jpg\" />"
}
```